# java.lang.IllegalStateException. Possible error with WebClassLoader

Tags: java, spring, exception, soap

I'm developing a web application with Spring and I have this strange error. I can't figure out where it comes from, I've been google'ing hard and found nothing so far.

In the project I'm using: MongoDB, Spring, WSS4J (X.509 security headers for soap), Apache CXF. I've been trying to discover whether there is something that causes this error, any particular action, behaviour, condition something, but I found nothing so far, sometimes it happens after 3 min of running sometimes after 3h or not at all, any clues and hints appreciated.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment$1.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1597)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment$HashIterator.<init>(Segment.java:988)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.hashIterator(Segment.java:936)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$HashIterator.<init>(DiskStore.java:1038)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeyIterator.<init>(DiskStore.java:1111)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeyIterator.<init>(DiskStore.java:1111)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore$KeySet.iterator(DiskStore.java:949)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskExpiryTask.run(DiskStorageFactory.java:838)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the ehcache thread is trying to interact with the application after the application has been stopped or redeployed. It happens only when ehcache reach limits you have in ehcache.xml and trying to overflow to disk.

Look at tomcat logs for warnings when stop your application:

> SEVERE: The web application [/APP] appears to have started a thread
>   named [Ehcache_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it.
>   This is very likely to create a memory leak

If find something like this, you should stop ecache properly in your ServletContextListener:

```
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent){
      CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown();
}
```

maybe with 1 sec sleep after that, to be sure ehcache is stopped.

As mentioned in http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq

> If the JVM keeps running after you stop using Ehcache, you should call
>   CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown() so that the threads are stopped
>   and cache memory is released back to the JVM. Calling shutdown also
>   insures that your persistent disk stores get written to disk in a
>   consistent state and will be usable the next time they are used. If
>   the CacheManager does not get shut down, it should not be a problem.
>   There is a shutdown hook which calls the shutdown on JVM exit.

Or you can set property `overflowToDisk="false"` in ehcache.xml or restart tomcat every time you deploy apllication.